# A directed graph and existence of vertex of finite degree

Tags: graph-theory

Let $\{1,...,k\}$ be a set of vertices of a directed graph, with no multiple edges. We say that paths $p$ and $f$ are disjoint by interior  vertices if they are disjoint or have a common first or last vertex.

There is an edge from $i_1$ to $i_2$ only if $i_1<i_2$.

Assume that it has a property that for every 4 vertices $v_1<v_2<v_3<v_4$. Let path $p_{3,2}$ from $v_3$ to $v_2$, and $p_{4,2}$ from $v_4$ to $v_2$ which has only one common vertex $v_2$ with $p_{3,2}$, and $p$ is a path from $v_3$ or $v_4$ into $v_1$ (which is disjoint from $p_{3,2}$ and $p_{4,2}$ by interior vertices), then there is no path between $v_3$ and $v_4$ to $v_1$ which is disjoint from $p_{4,2}$, $p_{3,2}$ and $p$ by interior vertices.

It's very easy to draw this property then say it...

Anyway, the question with which I am struggling is:

Question: is it true that there is always a vertex with degree less or equal then $3$? How about $4$?